# How to highlight specific record using SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have form in which when open form then all records shown on the block. User enter number on search option and specific record shown on the block. Now I want when search then all records remain on the block and highlight searched data.

```
BEGIN

SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('block',default_where,'column= '||:block2.column);
GO_BLOCK ('block');
EXECUTE_QUERY;

END;
```

How to achieve this target in oracle forms 11g

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please  refer below link . This will solve your problem.

You need to create a visual attribute and need to assign at item_instance_property level.

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/171952/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set `Current Record Visual Attribute Group` property of `block` to a spesific `Visual Attribute` which you'd like to highlight to the visited row of the `block`.

Then, provided the records are already queried and appears on the screen, a text field( `:block2.column` ) with a 
`WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger with the below code might be used to search among those records by entering the desired value and pressing enter :

```
 go_block('block');
 first_record;
 while :block2.column != :block.column
 loop
  next_record;
 end loop;
```

Comment: with this code search records very slow. I have upto 2000 records